# Reordering the levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how I can modify the below code to reorder the cells based on their frequencies in each levels of Year.

```
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

library(dplyr)  
Data <- group_by(Data,Year) %>%
 mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = -25) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Category, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = 25)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the function `arrange` after grouping:

```
#library(dplyr)  
Data <- Data %>% group_by(Year) %>%
        arrange(Frequency) %>%            #<---- Add this call
        mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))

#library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
        geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity", show.legend=FALSE) +
        geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = -25) +
        geom_text(aes(label = Category, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = 25)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Pierre Lafortune, Thanks so much for your suggestion, How can I use arrange when instead of Data <- group_by(Data,Year) %>%
 mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))  , I use Data<-ddply(Data, .(Var1), transform, pos = cumsum(Freq) - 0.5*Freq) ?

Comment: It means I can not use arrange function with ddply?

Comment: You can do it separately. Arrange with dplyr `Data <- Data %>% group_by(Year) %>% arrange(Frequency)` then do whatever you want next with `ddply`